# Use vector<int>::iterator by reference but with error

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};
    for(auto & it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

Hello all, in C++ I use iterator by reference such as "auto & it" and the compiler return the error

> " error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&' from an rvalue of type 'std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}'
>        for(auto & it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
>   ".

I know "auto it = vec.begin()" works fine but as we all know pass by reference will improve the efficiency in C++, so why this error occurs when I use "auto & it"?

Comment: Search for the error string `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type`. There are many duplicates.

Comment: *so why this error occurs when I use "auto & it"?* Please pay close attention to the details of the compiler error. You are not allowed to initialize a non-const reference from an rvalue.

Comment: Just use a range based for `for (auto &i : vec)`

Comment: 1. There is no pass by reference here; 2. Passing references doesn't necessarily improve performance; 3. Focusing on performance over correctness is a very bad move. (A program that does the wrong thing but does it very fast isn't as useful as you might think.)

Comment: As an aside, a `vector::iterator` is a small and highly optimized construct that is very cheap to construct and copy. Using a reference to it does not "improve the efficiency". At best it makes no difference.

Comment: vector::iterator is most likely a simple pointer (even in VS in release mode).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> so why this error occurs when I use "auto & it"?

See the return type of `begin`. It does not return a reference. It returns the iterator by value. Therefore the return value is a temporary in the rvalue category. Temporaries (rvalues) can not be bound to non-const lvalue references. This is what the error "*invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ... from an rvalue of type ...*" means.

Besides, modifying the `begin` pointer of the container would make little sense. It would have been silly for `begin` to return a reference.

Solution: Just create a copy of the iterator by declaring a non-reference value, just like you know works fine.

> but as we all know pass by reference will improve the efficiency in C++

This is nonsense. An arbitrarily placed reference is unlikely to improve efficiency. Besides, you aren't trying to *pass* a reference here. You are trying to bind a reference to an object returned by a function.

Almost, if not always, iterators are very fast to copy (`std::vector::iterator` certainly is) and the indirection that you may potentially introduce with a reference may well be less efficient.

Answer (score 5):

The [`std::vector::begin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) returns an rvalue (a temporary object). You cannot take a reference to a temporary object with `auto&` (non-const lvalue reference). If you wish to take the mentioned return value by reference, you can use `auto&&` instead of `auto&` but I don't recommend it.

Using `auto&&` will create a **mutable rvalue reference** to the return value of `std::vector::begin`. This will [extend its lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) but I recommend to use `auto` only.

Using rvalue references won't improve the efficiency of your code, the [compiler will optimize out](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) the copy/move of interator object returned from `std::vector::begin` by value.

Answer (score 0):

auto keyword gets the type as temporary object from the expression (std::vector::begin) 
since the it is temporary object and thus compiler cannot deduce to reference to it. 
auto& ( non-const lvalue)

The best approach in you case to use without reference **auto var** instead **auto &var**

If you are force to use Reference 
C++11 has introduced rvalue-reference, which can bind to temporary object change to && instead of & as below

```
 vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};
    for(auto && it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but to me the difference seems obvious: Akira explained _why_ the original code didn't work before giving the alternative, _and_ then said that it's not a good idea. You just said 'do this instead' with no explanation or justification.

Comment: @underscore_d I saw his without edit version of answer it was two line say to use && instead of & later was changed in details  btw if the ans is correct and  not proper explanation can be asked to explain.anway its ok :-)

Comment: Akira was also downvoted before his edit. Rather than give excuses and compare to others, I suggest you improve your own answers instead. Then you won't get downvotes.

Comment: @Rohini Singh, thank you anyway. I think propose an answer with the explanation is better:)